# IBM Worklight - How to retrieve an already-deployed .wlapp file?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have an already running Worklight application. We are planning to move to another production cluster tomorrow but I want to get the old .wlapp that is already deployed on the first cluster.

How can I get it? I could find a directory on the temp file of the WebSphere application server, but it is in an exploded form. When I zipped one of them and converted it to .wlapp, while the deployment was successfull, I had a Direct Update and the application failed to start...

Is it the right path?

Comment: Any reason you can't just rebuild the WL project and grab the new wlapps from bin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build your application in Worklight Studio, the build produces .wlapp files and stores them in the `yourProject\bin` folder, these files do not get deleted from the bin folder unless you've manually deleted them.

- appname-envname-version.wlapp
- appname-common-version.wlapp
- appname-all.wlapp

Where the `version` value changes depending on the value you've set in `yourProject\yourApp\application-descriptor.xml`.

A good practice would be to backup your artifacts of different versions as well as project source code (using a source control system...), so you could always restore any version... esp. if you're talking about already being in Production....

---

After deployment, the .wlapp file is not stored in the filesystem, but in the database.

So as for retrieving previously deployed .wlapp files if you **do not** have backup (this is very bad, BTW), these are stored in your database in the `APP_SYNC_DATA` table in the `deployable` column. You can try to extract and save the APP_SYNC_DATA.deployable data relevant for you as a .wlapp file.

But this really does not guarantee that it will "work" any better than your other attempt. That .wlapp is configured to work with certain server URLs, and if this new cluster is not a replica of the previous cluster, I don't see this working either... But also, without knowing more about the errors you get, who knows to what they are related (but this is NOT for this question).

Comment: Yes in fact the app is in production and I released many versions of iphone-1.0 via direct update. I built another version locally and forgot to backup the last deployed iphone wlapp. Now when switching to the new server I want to keep the same deployed wlapp. Is that possible ?