# How can I backup .wlapp?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When I install (upload) new .wlapp file in application's console, I would like to make backup of the existing application set up. I am not sure where unZIPed wlapp files located after they uploaded via console, so I don't know, which folder to backup.

Also, is .wlapp makes modification of database and filesystem backup is not enough in this case?

Or, rephrase question: what can I do to backup current wlapp before trying new wlapp install. So I can safely back out if anything went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The .wlapp is located in the following location inside of your workspace:

/"WORKSPACE_NAME"/"PROJECT_NAME"/bin

On a successful build of your project the .wlapp for your environments will be found in the above location. You will see environment specific .wlapps as well as one that includes all of the environments. If you wish to backup these files you can simply copy them to another location after a successful build. Also as a note if you update the version of application environments inside of your applicationDescriptor these wlapps should manage each specific version in the bin folder as well. For example:

FormBasedAuthApp-iphone-1.0.wlapp

FormBasedAuthApp-iphone-2.0.wlapp

Once the wlapp is deployed it is actually stored in the database and it is much harder to guarantee exporting this resource. Please look Idan's post here for suggestions on this topic:

[IBM Worklight - How to retrieve an already-deployed .wlapp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472404/ibm-worklight-how-to-retrieve-an-already-deployed-wlapp-file)

Comment: How are you deploying the wlapps? I am assuming you would have to build the apps before deploying them. The above solution is ideal in order to backup your apps before deployment. Once the wlapp is deployed it is actually stored in the database and it is much harder to guarantee exporting this resource. Please look Idan's post here for suggestions on this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472404/ibm-worklight-how-to-retrieve-an-already-deployed-wlapp-file

Comment: @Barat I see you have deleted your comment. If these answers satisfy your question can you please mark the question as answered. Or if you have any further questions please let me know

Comment: I am not sure who deleted my comment, not likely it was me. Indeed, I mentioned that answer is not relevant to question, as I asked about server side deployment, NOT development environment with workspace.

Comment: I added a comment yesterday with server side details. I just edited my post in order to reflect this. Please let me know if this information does not satisfy your question.

Answer (score 1):

The wlapp file once uploaded to Server becomes a part of Database and can not be retrieved as a normal file for backup.

The best practice is to keep the wlapp file in a separate backup and also making sure that you change the version before building a new wlapp (especially for the production environment)