# Location of WLAPP files on Worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Does anyone know what will be the locaton of wlapp files on worklight server, once you deploy the wlapp files it should be copying the same to some location, I am trying to back up some wlapp files from server and enable to find the location of same.

Comment: Thanks since this is duplicate will close this question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your application in Worklight Studio, the build produces .wlapp files and stores them in the yourProject\bin folder, these files do not get deleted from the bin folder unless you've manually deleted them.

After deployment, the .wlapp file is not stored in the filesystem, but in the database.
So as for retrieving previously deployed .wlapp files if you do not have backup (this is very bad, BTW), these are stored in your database in the APP_SYNC_DATA table in the deployable column. You can try to extract and save the APP_SYNC_DATA.deployable data relevant for you as a .wlapp file.

More here: [IBM Worklight - How to retrieve an already-deployed .wlapp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472404/ibm-worklight-how-to-retrieve-an-already-deployed-wlapp-file)